# Different between declaring static variable before or after static block in java

Tags: java

**The code 1:**

```
       public class StaticBlockExample1
      {
        static {  value = 20;  }

        static int value = 10;
        public static void main(String[] args) {

              System.out.println(" Value = " + value);
        }
    }
```

output of StaticBlockExample1 is 10

**The code 2:**

```
  public class StaticBlockExample2 
      {
        static int value = 10;
        static {    value = 20;     }   

        public static void main(String[] args)
           {
            System.out.println(" Value = " + value);
           }
      }
```

output of StaticBlockExample2 is 20.

Am confused with outputs of the above examples. is there any significance to declare static variable before or after static block?

Answer (score 14):

Yes, the static block and the static field initializations are executed in the order in which they are found in the input file.

Answer (score 1):

The most important is order of your inicializations. 
- 1st case  - 10 is defined as second

static int value = 10;

and in 2nd case ,  block is second

```
  static {
            value = 20;
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

order of initialization is different

first: you define static block before variable declaration

second: you define static block after variable declaration